# Issue with my random number generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a random number generator where you enter the min and max values. However, when I enter in let's say 0 as the min and 100 as the max I get value like 270, 690, 180, 580, 70, 240, etc.

```js
function random_number(min, max) {
  max = $("#max_num").val();
  min = $("#min_num").val();
  document.getElementById("random_num").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter max number: <input type="text" id="max_num"><br/> Enter min number: <input type="text" id="min_num"><br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="random_number()">Random number</button><br/>
  <div id="random_num"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to coerce the values of your inputs (strings) to numbers using the unary `+` operator:

```js
function random_number(min,max){
    max = +$("#max_num").val();
    min = +$("#min_num").val();
    document.getElementById("random_num").textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter max number: <input type="text" id="max_num"><br/>
Enter min number: <input type="text" id="min_num"><br/>
<button type="button" onclick="random_number()">Random number</button><br/>
<span id="random_num"></span></p>
```